# Volley - DiskBasedCache OutOfMemory Exception - Array size too large

Tags: android, android-volley

```
  public void parseInfo(String genderTxt2, Boolean gender){
        final String URL = "url" +
                "?adult=" + isAdult.toString() + "&gender=" + genderTxt2;

        info_text.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        listview_progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        mRequestQueue.add(new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,URL,null,new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                try {

                    if (!fPullToRefreshAttacher.isRefreshing()) {
                        names.clear();
                    }

                    VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));

                    adapter.clear();
                    parseJSON(response);



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
               // VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage().toString());
                Toast.makeText(acc, "Unable to load names list! Please check connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }));

  mRequestQueue.start();

    }
```

Simple enough, getting OutOfMemory exception on a number of devices. any ideas?

http://crashes.to/s/834735fdc1b/details

Comment: Include a stack trace. Where exactly is the OOM exception being thrown? Is the String/JSON response very very large?

Comment: Response is the same size each time, 100 items. and ill post the exception now

Comment: Please see link above

Comment: @xBroak cool crash report service! anyway, about the OOM, could you please tell us about the size of the response (in terms of tree depth and number of characters for example) , or just show a sample? it's weird since OOM is usually caused by bitmaps and not json responses, even if they are quite big...

Comment: Thanks! The HPROF seems to keep mentioning bitmaps too, but i'm doing NO bitmap handling at startup yet my heap is almost full! the only time i use bitmaps is in a seperate activity. its a simple response with 100 entries at all times, 4 attributes per entry, name, gender, isAdult, url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have ran into a similar issue before. What's happening is you are getting the entire `JSON` object in memory before parsing it. What you want to do it use some kind of reader to Stream it.

https://sites.google.com/site/gson/streaming

From the doc:

> Most applications should use only the object model API. JSON streaming is useful in just a few situations:
>
> When it is impossible or undesirable to load the entire object model into memory. This is most relevant on mobile platforms where memory is limited.
>
> When it is necessary to read or write a document before it is completely available.

Comment: Any idea if this is supported by Volley? and how?

Comment: From looking at Volley source it seems like they are processing the requests in `RequestQueue` in sequence and not parallel with `PriorityBlockingQueue`. I achieved the same thing by queuing Intent Service, and using Gson streaming. From this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17734789/volley-outofmemoryerror) it seems like Volley doesn't currently support streaming.

Comment: Could i not use an endless loading adapter to limit the number of json entries loaded at a time?

Comment: If you could control the size of the JSON, and make it fit in memory then of course, since that might be a smaller change for you. But also keep in mind that if the JSON do get bigger in the future you'll be back to the same problem.

Comment: Ok, i decided to get a  StringRequest myReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, URL,
                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                createMyReqErrorListener()); using volley and then use 'jackson' to parse the JSON, is this a good workaround?

Comment: Jackson also have streaming support, so yes that would be a viable workaround.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UWA2EZ4r correct streaming implementation? definatley getting less OOM

Comment: @wangyif2 +1 thanks for the info, can you help me to convert my vollehelper class to use gson streaming concept? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21746202/how-to-avoid-volley-outofmemory-with-json-streaming-concept