# how to implement JSON streaming concept for volley to avoid OutOfMemory error?

Tags: android, json, caching, gson, android-volley

I have recently got one bug in my volley implementation, I'm not using any image loading concept of volley, I'm using it for calling more that 10 REST api calls in view-pager  `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` one http restapi call per one  swipe, everything works fine, but the app got crashed few times, If I run the app 1000 times, it crashes only 5 times.

**Error Log:**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: 
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.streamToBytes(DiskBasedCache.java:316)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readString(DiskBasedCache.java:526)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.readStringStringMap(DiskBasedCache.java:549)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache$CacheHeader.readHeader(DiskBasedCache.java:392)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache.initialize(DiskBasedCache.java:155)
 E/AndroidRuntime(5798): at com.android.volley.CacheDispatcher.run(CacheDispatcher.java:85)
```

By Googling I found the solution we have to use this **JSON streaming** concept

**Details:**

> Most applications should use only the object model API. JSON streaming
>   is useful in just a few situations:When it is impossible or
>   undesirable to load the entire object model into memory. This is most
>   relevant on mobile platforms where memory is limited.When it is
>   necessary to read or write a document before it is completely
>   available.

**What I'm looking for?:**

I'm trying to find solution for my volley OutOfMemory with JSON streaming, I'm thinking of how can convert my Volley Helper class to use JSON streaming.

**Here is my Volley helper class:**

```
public class GsonRequest<T> extends Request<T> {
private final Gson gson = new Gson();
private final Class<T> clazz;
private final Map<String, String> headers;
private final Listener<T> listener;

/**
* Make a GET request and return a parsed object from JSON.
*
* @param url URL of the request to make
* @param clazz Relevant class object, for Gson's reflection
* @param headers Map of request headers
*/
public GsonRequest(String url, Class<T> clazz, Map<String, String> headers,
Listener<T> listener, ErrorListener errorListener) {
super(Method.GET, url, errorListener);
this.clazz = clazz;
this.headers = headers;
this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
return headers != null ? headers : super.getHeaders();
}

@Override
protected void deliverResponse(T response) {
listener.onResponse(response);
}

@Override
protected Response<T> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
try {
String json = new String(
response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
return Response.success(
gson.fromJson(json, clazz), HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
} catch (JsonSyntaxException e) {
return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
}
}
}
```

Can any one guide me to convert above class to use JSON streaming concept to avoid to load the entire object model into memory in volley?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure!  May be with new Okttp Supports java NIO will solve these problem!

**Okhttp** 2.0 RC is now dependent on **[Okio](https://github.com/square/okio)** to support **java.io** and **java.nio** to make it much easier to access, store, and process your data using ByteString and Buffer to do some clever things to save CPU and memory.(FYI This remembers me Koush's OIN library with NIO support!) I hope this will solve my issue! I will update this Answer once I confirm it correctly.

Comment: @maxxxo Try with Volley Singleton pattern ! Reuse the request que object !! may be I'm not used that Singleton pattern !! Now works fine with latest Okhttp !!  FYI is you want use volley like Retrofit Dot pattern use Volley custom lib called https://github.com/orhanobut/wasp